# Conditional statement for function with "Or"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am struggling with getting the right output for my code. The code keeps giving me the wrong state as my output, what am I doing wrong?

```
def whatState(cityName):
    if cityName == "dallas" or "austin" or "houston" or "ft worth" or "el paso":
        stateName = "Texas"
    elif cityName == "sacramento" or "san francisco" or "los angeles" or "san diego":
        stateName = "California"
    elif cityName == "miami" or "west palm beach" or "orlando" or "key west" or "tallahassee":
        stateName = "Florida"
    elif cityName == "chicago" or "naperville" or "peoria" or "evanston" or "rockford":
        stateName = "Illinois"

    return stateName
```

When I try testing my code with chicago I'm getting Texas as my output, when I should be getting Illinois

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be:

```
def stateName(cityName):
    if cityName in ["dallas", "austin", "houston", "ft worth", "el paso"]:
        stateName = "Texas"
    elif cityName in... 

    return stateName
```